# obtener los 3 mayores valores de un array

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este array:

`var array = [43, 12, 11, 8, 1134, 90, 50, 10, 70];`

Mi pregunta es de que forma puedo obtener los **3** valores mayores usando JavaScript.

Que como resultado final yo obtenga en consola estos números: [1134, 90, 70].

De antemano, gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `sort()` para ordenar el arreglo de mayor a menor y luego obtener únicamente los primeros 3 índices

```
let arrDes = [43, 12, 11, 8, 1134, 90, 50, 10, 70];
function top3(numbers) {  
  numbers = numbers.sort((a,b) => b - a);
  return [numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]];
};

console.log(top3(arrDes));
```

Explicación:

Primero ordenas el arreglo de mayor a menor con `sort((a,b) => b - a)` y luego obtienes únicamente los primeros 3 índices del arreglo ordenado

Comment: Gracias! @HeytalePazguato